# B is A's Jordan form, so that there's an invertible matrix P so that $A=PBP^{-1}$. How do I find P?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

B is A's Jordan form, so that there's an invertible matrix P so that $A=PBP^{-1}$. How do I find P? I tried solving, and here's a detailed path of my solution. Any help is very much appreciated!

For example:

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&-3&4 \\ 4&-7&8\\ 6&-7&7 \end{matrix}\right)$$ I found A's eigenvalues to be $λ_1=λ_2=-1$ and $λ_3=3$, and the corresponding eigenvectors I found to be, for -1: $(1,2,1)$, and for 3: $(1,2,2)$.

So I calculated and for A's jordan form to be: $$B=\left(\begin{matrix}-1&1&0 \\ 0&-1&0\\ 0&0&3 \end{matrix}\right)$$

So that there is an invetible matrix P so that $A=PBP^{-1}$. I tried finding P in the following method, but got confused trying...

Let $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ be P's collums. Thus:

$A=PBP^{-1}$

$AP=PB$

$A(p_1,p_2,p_3)=(p_1,p_2,p_3)B$

So now I multiply by collums:

$1) A\cdot p_1=(-1) \cdot p_1$

$2) A\cdot p_2=1 \cdot p_1+(-1) \cdot p_2$

$3) A\cdot p_3=3 \cdot p_3$

Conclusions:

(1): So $-1$ is an eigenvalue with corresponding eigenvector $p_1$, so that means $p_1=(1,2,1)$.

(3): So $3$ is an eigenvalue with corresponding eigenvector $p_3$, so that means $p_3=(1,2,2)$.

And (2) is the problem now...

(2): $(A+I)\cdot p_2=p_1$

We know from (1) that $(A+I)\cdot p_1=0$, so we multiply both sides with $(A+I):

$(A+I)^2\cdot p_2=0$

$\left(\begin{matrix}1&-3&4 \\ 4&-7&8\\ 6&-7&7 \end{matrix}\right) \cdot \left(\begin{matrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)$

Solving that gave me **two** vectors: $(1,1,0)$ and $(-1,0,1)$. Which one is correct, and why? Wolfram Alpha told me that $(-1,-1,0)$ is the right one. Why the change of sign?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the long post.

Comment: Columns of $P$ are basis of generalized eigenspace.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly change of sign in wolfram alpha doesn't matter, since when you take the inverse matrix it is also changed.

The reason you get 2 vectors is since $p_1$ is in their span.

Then: $(-1,0,1)+\alpha(1,1,0)=(1,2,1)$ has a solution and $(1,1,0)$ is the vector you seek.